# Python // Lambda: invalid syntax

Tags: python, lambda

I'm trying to iterate on a dataframe. I want to replace a few characters by anothers, unless the item I'm iterating is null/nan/NaN/etc.

For that I'm trying to use this line below:

```
lista['ultima_receita'] = lista['ultima_receita'].apply(lambda rstr: float(rstr.replace('.','').replace(',','.')[3:]) if pd.isnull(rstr) == False)
```

However it keeps getting me a invalid synthax error:

```
    lista['ultima_receita'] = lista['ultima_receita'].apply(lambda rstr: float(rstr.replace('.','').replace(',','.')[3:]) if pd.isnull(rstr) == False)
                                                                                                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried everything I could and didn't find out the reason why the synthax is wrong. Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making your question simpler.  The `lambda` is indeed the issue, so this has nothing to do with pandas here.

```
>>> lambda rstr: float(rstr.replace('.','').replace(',','.')[3:]) if pd.isnull(rstr) == False
SyntaxError: invalid syntax  # At the end of 'False' above
```

or even simpler:

```
>>> lambda x: "foo" if "bar" == False
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is because python needs an `else` for the `A if B else C` construction.  If you want to do a conditional modification you could make this `else rstr`, or use other pandas / numpy logic to do different logic.

```
>>> func = lambda x: "foo" if "bar" in x else x
>>> func("isobaric"), func("agnostic")
('foo', 'agnostic')
```